# Dynamic measure that updates based on slicer selection

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to create a measure that `counts` the number of Mondays and will `update` based on the `date` range slicer I have created. For example, if I select all of March with my date slicer, the measure will be 5. If I select all of March and back to February 20, it would show 6. I tried the below code and it just calculates the total number of Mondays in the entire dataset and doesn't change when I adjust the date range slicer.

```
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[DATE]),WEEKDAY('Table'[DATE]) = 2),0)
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new DAX column

```
Weekday = WEEKDAY('Table'[Date])
```

and the following measure:

```
Measure = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Column1]); 'Table'[Weekday] = 2)
```

this way it works. 
But I am wondering this one doesnt work (similar to your ones because your expression should have worked also)

```
Measure = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Column1]); WEEKDAY([Column1]) = 2)
```

when it should also work ?!?!

Comment: Thanks for the help.  However, this method still is not updating when I change the date range slicer.  If I expand to show the whole range of dates, it shows 2098 (all the rows in my dataset), but if cut it down to just a week or two, it still shows 2098.  If I filter down to just Monday in my measure, it shows 426, but again, doesn't update if I change the date range.

Comment: Never mind.  I think I've got it now.  Thank you for your help!